# DataGridViewRow numerically order

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, rows

How can I sort my DataGridViewRow to  numerically order?

My code:

```
Dim Name As New List(Of String)
Dim Price As New List(Of Integer)

   For x = 0 To Math.Max(Name.Count, Price.Count)
                If x < Name.Count AndAlso x < Price.Count Then
                Dim row As String() = New String() {Name(x), Price(x)}
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
            End If
        Next
```

Price row example:

```
1345
1533
4555
6744
```

Comment: If `Price` contains `Integer` values then why are you putting `Price(x)` into a `String` array?  Add the values as `Integers` rather than `Strings` if they are in fact `Integers`.  As for sorting, you simply click a column header or call the grid's `Sort` method.

Comment: example? I don't know how can I do it.

Comment: What is the type of the parameter for that `Add` method that you're calling?  Have you looked?  If not, why not?  It is in fact `Object()`.  If the method takes an `Object` array, which can contain objects of any type, then why pass it a `String` array, which can only contain `String` objects?

Comment: name(x) is constain string.

Comment: So?  Does `Price(x)` contain a `String`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got them as two separate lists... I'll take a leap and make an assumption that you need to keep the source data in that format... Having them in two lists you've currently got a dependency on their positions.  So use a sortable collection to pair them up

e.g.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Data.Linq

    Dim Name As New List(Of String)
    Dim Price As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim Sortable As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer))

    'Your checking that you weren't going past the last pair was an odd one
    For x = 0 To Math.Min(Name.Count, Price.Count) - 1
        'Pair them up so you can sort them together not having to try to match between two lists
        Sortable.Add(New KeyValuePair(Name(x), Price(x)))
    Next

    'now you can sort it
    Sortable = (From item In Sortable Order By Convert.ToInt32(item.Key) Select item).ToList()

    'now stick it in the grid view, You might be able to base the grid view on the 
    'DataGridView1.DataSource = Sortable
    'DataGridView1.DataBind()
    'depends on how it is defined/configured, 
    'but for now let us return to your original code....
    For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In Sortable
        Dim row As String() = New String() {kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToString("$0.00")}
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
    Next
```

Comment: NameValuePair is not defined.

Comment: not good, namevalue error again and I get error to kvp.Price.ToString("$0.00")} also. Error 2 'Price' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)'."

Comment: kvp.Value.ToString, I was rushing during lunch... Corrected above. There are no NameValuePair left in my example.

Comment: Obviously you can use whatever ToString format instruction is appropriate for your environment.

Comment: Thank you for your helping. Error 1 Too few type arguments to 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue)'."

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1